# CRTP: use static constexpr from derived class

Tags: c++

My CRTP derived class has some compile-time fixed dimension that I define using a `static constexpr`. Now I want to use it as a static variable from the base class. How do I do this?

Example:

```cpp
#include <array>

template <class D>
class Base
{
public:
    void myfunc()
    {
        auto n = derived_cast().n;
        std::array<size_t, n> a;
    }

private:
    auto derived_cast() -> D&
    {
        return *static_cast<D*>(this);
    }

    auto derived_cast() const -> const D&
    {
        return *static_cast<const D*>(this);
    }
};

class A : public Base<A>
{
public:
    A() = default;

private:
    friend class Base<A>;
    static constexpr size_t n = 2;
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    a.myfunc();

    return 0;
}
```

This fails with:

```cpp
error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
        std::array<size_t, n> a;
                           ^
```

I also thought about using

```cpp
std::array<size_t, derived_cast().n> a;
```

but that fails with:

```
error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
        std::array<size_t, derived_cast().n> a;
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So what should I put?

Comment: `auto n = derived_cast().n;` should be `constexpr auto n = D::n;`

Comment: To put it in perspective... `int m = 2;` - m is initialized by a constant expression, but it's pretty clear it isn't usable in constant expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto n = derived_cast().n;` should be:

```
constexpr auto n = D::n;
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0c326cc265fa647)

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
std::array<size_t, D::n>
```